# Making my microcontroller transmit audio to any bluetooth headphones/speakers

Tags: wireless-communication, audio-engineering, microelectronics

I am creating a microcontroller on a custom PCB design for an MP3 player. I would like to consider integrating bluetooth into it. When I say integrating bluetooth into it, I specifically mean transmitting the chosen song on my custom MP3 player to any bluetooth speaker device that has been connected to it.

Most of what I see on the web specifically talks about receiving audio. AKA, audio from a cellphone would be provided to my system and music will be played. This is the opposite functionality of what I really want (although if the module supports both, that is fine).

I've taken a look at this module:

- [RN52 Bluetooth Audio Module](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/RN52%20DATASHEET-1.0r-1181113.pdf)
- [RN-52 Bluetooth Hookup Guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/rn-52-bluetooth-hookup-guide)
- [SparkFun Audio Bluetooth Breakout - RN-52](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12849?_ga=2.256381579.1238042627.1520609890-762015303.1514738678)

It looks promising, but all of the projects I see in reference to it are still the receiving design. Whenever it talks about audio out, it also specifically mentions the MIC IN pins. Since my data coming in isn't technically through a MIC, I didn't know if this functioned the way I would expect. From what I gather, MIC IN tends to only support 8Khz, while MP3 files are up to 48KHz.

The other one I was looking at:

- [Microchips BM62/64 Bluetooth® 4.2 Stereo Audio Module](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001403C.pdf)

This one seems to have a lot of the buzz words I've found while researching this, such PCM formatting, but the pictures on the page labeled 5 once again only show receiving data from a Bluetooth device such as a cellphone.

All other projects that I see that involve transmitting to anything also involve having a second custom microcontroller and Bluetooth module on the receive end. Instead, I want the receive end to be any generic Bluetooth audio receiver; similar to how I can pair any Bluetooth device to my cellphone and output it from my cellphone to the headphones.

Any direction or confirmation of functionality would be great.

Comment: Better on the Electrical Engineering stack?

Comment: Didn't realize this wasn't the EE stack o.o. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Take a look at [Understanding the BC127 Bluetooth Module](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/understanding-the-bc127-bluetooth-module/all) and [WT32i REFERENCE DESIGN
APPLICATION NOTE](https://www.silabs.com/documents/login/reference-designs/Reference-Design-DKWT32i.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There are Bluetooth adapters available which will hook into audio system via 3mm jack or optical jack and broadcast the music to your headset.

However if you want to receive the music into your phone, you need another adapter to hook into your phone audio jack.

I have both and they cost me $20 each.

Comment: Can you share some details of the required adapter to received bluetooth music to the phone such as a part number or product name?